# unable to execute array query in php

Tags: php, pdo, insert, prepared-statement, execute

```
$stmtt=$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `dbname` (`Shop_ID`,`Shop_name`,`Shop_owner_name`,`Shop_phone1`,`Shop_phone2`,`Shop_category`,`Shop_address`,`Shop_pincode`,`Shop_state`,`Shop_add_by_user_id`) VALUES (:shopid,:shopname,:shopownername,:shopphone1,:shopphone2,:shopcategory,:shopaddress,:shoppincode,:shopstate,:shopaddbyuserid)");

$stmtt->execute(array(':shopid' => $shop_id_n, ':shopname' => $shop_name, ':shopownername' => $shop_owner_name, ':shopphone1' => $shop_phone1, ':shopphone2' => $shop_phone2, ':shopcategory' => $shop_category, ':shopaddress' => $shop_address, ':shoppincode' => $shop_pincode, ':shopstate' => $shop_state, ':shopaddbyuserid' => $shop_add_by_user_id));
trigger_error("PDO errorInfo: ".$dbh->errorInfo());
if(($stmtt->rowCount())>0)
{
    return "true";
}
else
{
    return "false";
}
```

after executing above code i am getting error like:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in /home/tnuwgfoah4wc/public_html/dbconn/functions.php on line 109

Notice: PDO errorInfo: Array in /home/tnuwgfoah4wc/public_html/dbconn/functions.php on line 109
```

i have tried every possible method but unable to find the error....
can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Don't put quotes around your placeholders. `':shopid'` should be `:shopid`

Comment: I have removed the quotes, still not working....

Comment: Enable error-reporting and get the actual error. That way, nobody has to guess what's wrong.. ;-)

Comment: i have added trigger_error in the code and relevant error is being displayed

Comment: I added a link to the answer that actually helps you to get the error message.

Comment: Thank You @YourCommonSense .... got the error message and resolved...